# Completely disabling objects outside the camera's angle

Tags: scripting, eevee-render-engine

Is it possible to write a ‘Script’ that will completely disable all objects outside the camera angle?
every time I start the script I want all objects except camera angle to be disabled.

The reason I want this is because I am using Eevee render and Render is running out of memory. There are thousands of objects in my scene. It is very difficult to disable them all one by one.

I’m just wondering if something like this is possible.

I don’t think the engine disabled it, I’m pretty sure it loads ‘Shaders’ for invisible objects.
What I really want is to prevent objects that are not visible from the camera angle from loading 'Shaders'.

Comment: I think eevee already does that by default. You can try using this technique with geometry nodes https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KoLF99PFLFM

Comment: Have you tried checking "Simplify" under the render setting tab?